# How to solve this . The process cannot access the file

Tags: vb.net

The process cannot access the file 'F:\copy back up\system\HRM 2-5-2013\HRM\HRM\lanbased.txt' because it is being used by another process.
This is my code in sub main

```
Public localhost As String
Public username As String
Public port As String
Public database As String
Public conn As New MySqlConnection
Public NAME1 As String = "F:\copy back up\system\HRM 2-5-2013\HRM\HRM\lanbased.txt"

Public Sub main()
    Dim frm As New Form1
    Dim frm1 As New create

    If System.IO.File.Exists(NAME1) = True Then
        Try
            Dim objReader As New System.IO.StreamReader(NAME1)

            localhost = objReader.ReadLine() & vbNewLine
            username = objReader.ReadLine() & vbNewLine
            port = objReader.ReadLine() & vbNewLine
            database = objReader.ReadLine() & vbNewLine
            conn.ConnectionString = "server=" & Trim(localhost) & ";user id=" & Trim(username) & "; password=" & Trim(port) & "; database=" & Trim(database) & ""
            conn.Open()


            Application.Run(New Form1())
        Catch ex As Exception
            MsgBox("Unable  to connect to database", vbCritical)

            Application.Run(New create())
        End Try
    End If
    Exit Sub
End Sub
```

and this is my code in my form create.
How do I access the file when it is being used by another process?

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Dim FILE_NAME As String = "F:\copy back up\system\HRM 2-5-2013\HRM\HRM\lanbased.txt"

    If TextBox1.Text = Nothing Or TextBox2.Text = Nothing Or TextBox3.Text = Nothing Or TextBox4.Text = Nothing Then
        MsgBox("fill up mo pa ngot")

    ElseIf System.IO.File.Exists(FILE_NAME) = True Then

        Dim objWriter As New System.IO.StreamWriter(FILE_NAME)


        objWriter.Write(TextBox1.Text + vbCrLf)
        objWriter.Write(TextBox2.Text + vbCrLf)
        objWriter.Write(TextBox3.Text + vbCrLf)
        objWriter.Write(TextBox4.Text + vbCrLf)
        objWriter.Close()

        TextBox1.Clear()
        TextBox2.Clear()
        TextBox3.Clear()
        TextBox4.Clear()

    ElseIf conn.State = True Then

        MsgBox("maka connect naka")

    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: check if this executable is running twice ( in Task Manager )

Comment: no.. the problem is in the code.. the file F:\copy back up\system\HRM 2-5-2013\HRM\HRM\lanbased.txt is being used twice how can i used this file twice..??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

first you open your file for reading here :

```
Dim objReader As New System.IO.StreamReader(NAME1)    //1st open
```

Second you call the form1 : `Application.Run(New Form1())`

in that Form you have :  `Dim objWriter As New System.IO.StreamWriter(FILE_NAME)  //2nd open`

But wait `you didn't close your file` so you can't open it 2nd time for writing.

So you need to close the file `before calling create form 1`  like `objReader.close()`

```
        conn.Open()
        objReader.close()    <----- this one
        Application.Run(New Form1())
```

Comment: now i got this error :((Unable to connect to any of the specified MySQL hosts.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you need to close your streamReader before opening the new form:

```
objReader.Close()
```

That will free the file.

Comment: SysDragon i used your code and still have the same problem :((